# Request limited set of friends based on condition using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is there a way to e.g. get all friends who like a specific tv show using the Facebook graph API?

Comment: You can use fql to achieve this. All my friends that like Father Ted: SELECT uid, first_name, last_name FROM user WHERE uid IN(SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id='306411942918' AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()))

Comment: please paste as answer and I'll 'accept'

Answer (score -2):

You could have used fql to achieve this before Graph v2.0 came into effect.

All my friends that like Father Ted:

`SELECT uid, first_name, last_name FROM user WHERE uid IN(SELECT uid FROM page_fan WHERE page_id='306411942918' AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()))`

Using Graph API:

`https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?fields=first_name,last_name,likes{id}&<ACCESS_TOKEN>`

Once you get all the results of your friend's likes you can then iterate through them in your code and check them against a specific id.

Comment: that is not Graph API.

Comment: I've edited the answer to reflect how to do it with the Graph API.